# C# ASP convert parameters to utf8

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8

I have a trouble with my app, one of my customers is sending me data in wrong format, so I have to decode it first to utf8.

> Roteb%FCh

this "%FC" is an "ü" in ISO-8859-1

But all I get in my app is

> Roteb�h

and I can't encode it any more... is there a filter for controller to do this before data get converted or even url encoded?

```
public ActionResult Register(string adressXML)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to parse the post data like this:

```
string data = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
string xmlData = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

then I can convert string to utf8